# Как организовать личные сообщения?

Tags: php, sql, ajax

Есть сайдбар, где выводятся фотки юзеров из базы данных, при наводки курсора на фотографию, появляется блок, где есть вариант отправить личное сообщение. При клике я узнаю id данного юзера и перехожу на страницу где будет происходить сама переписка. Собственно вопрос, id того самого пользователя я загнал в переменную и она осталась на странице sidebar.php, а как мне ее передать на страницу message.php например? Чтобы потом свой id и пользователя отправить в базу данных.

И вообще логика правильная?

Comment: message.php?uid=<ID пользователя которому пишут сообщение>

Comment: А вы не могли бы подробнее мне немного объяснить, либо скинуть ссылку где я могу об этом почитать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id` пользователя после его авторизации с паролем, наверное, вы храните [в сессии](http://php.net/manual/ru/session.examples.basic.php)? А при переходе на страницу диалога можно `id` адресата просто передавать в GET-параметре:

```
message.php?to=12345
```

Там вы из сессии узнаете `id` *от кого*, и из GET-параметра – *кому*.

Именно так, в частности, устроены личные сообщения ВКонтакте. Адрес страницы диалога с пользователем с id=1 (Павлом Дуровым) имеет вид `vk.com/im?sel=1`

Comment: логику понял, сейчас почитаю про get, спасибо!